# C# Using Multiple Files in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, using

I have a file, Tools.cs, with a class in it, Tools. I use another file, Default.cs, as the codebehind to my Default.aspx. I've tried all of the below to use the tools file in the default file, but nothing works. How can I do this?

```
using Tools;
using Global.Tools; //Added namespace Global to my tools class
using Global;
```

EDIT: To be more throrough, here's some code.

```
//Tools.cs
namespace Global{
    public sealed class Tools{
     //Tools stuff
    }
}

//Default.cs

using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using Global; 

namespace Home{
    public class Default :Page{
        //Page stuff
    }
}
```

and I get the error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Global' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a namespace called something other than "Global".

Comment: +1 Normally you will want to name namespace, parameter, property to something not a keyword or commonly use in programming language.

Comment: Yeah, in the final code I plan to. This doesn't fix anything though. The issue is, I believe, the Tools.cs isn't building. I'm doing all of this in notepad++ on a shared folder that reconciles to our webserver.

Answer (score 3):

The `using` directive *isn't for files*, it's for **namespaces**.

```
using YourToolsNamespace;
```

Where `YourToolsNamespace` is what contains your `Tools` class.

**Edit**: you will also need to have this in your project references.  For instance, you can reference your code library from the GAC, another project, or a specific location.  Right-click on references and find your assembly there.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I've added the namespace Global around my class. But there has to be a reference to the file somehow, or the namespace isn't recognized. I've edited the above post to include a more thorough example and error code.

Comment: If you type "Global." (without quotes) does the intellisense recognise Tools as within that namespace?  Are both classes in the same project?  Is there any scope definition on Tools e.g. private/public?

Comment: There is no intellisense, no right click on references, or anything like that. I'm building this as raw files in notepad++ without any bells or whistles due to a lack of software. How do I add the reference so it knows to compile the Tools.cs so that the namespace is even visible?

Comment: Take a look a my answer. It may be the reason why there is no intelisesne.

Comment: I responded to you Alex, and I agree the Tools.cs probably isn't building. And there is not intelisense because I'm using notepad++ (see comment above yours here). I have no web.config (unless I create it by hand) or any other config file. How do I set the properties to build given this environment?

Comment: @steventnorris Do you not have the ability to download the free version of Visual C#?  It'll save you a lot of heartache.

Comment: I'm waiting on a spending clerance to get Visual Studio, it just hasn't come through yet. In the meantime, this is the best I can do.

Comment: @steventnorris I won't keep beating a dead horse, but Visual C# is free and you can easily install Visual Studio on top of it no problem.

Comment: It's not an issue of what I want, because I'd go for it. It's a corporate environment with a strict list of approved applications that I have to work with. Out of my hands. Any solution for my current situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reference it within the Default.aspx, edit your web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="WebApplication1.SubNamespace"/>
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and your class may look like this:

```
namespace WebApplication1.SubNamespace
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static string value { get { return "hello world!!"; } }
    }
}
```

this will make it referable within aspx markup like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <%= Class1.value %>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where can I find the web.config?

Comment: Its in the root of your web project. Is this your first .NET web app? :-)

Comment: No, it's the third or so, but I'm creating everything by hand so I have no web.config unless I make it (no Visual Studio yet. Waiting on an IS install so my hands are tied.)

Comment: oh ok :-) you are notepadding it I guess. I added the basic file to the answer. hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a build problem now though, based on some research. I see namespace references, but my problem is the Tools.cs isn't even compiling into a workable dll i believe.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Tools class is set to compile in the Properties --> Build Action.

Also, to use it you may have to do something like this:

_Default.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ThisWorks.Fine;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tools tools = new Tools();
    }
}
```

And

Tools.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ThisWorks.Fine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Tools
    /// </summary>
    public class Tools
    {
        public Tools() { }
        //Tools stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I set it to build? I'm using notepad++ to create this files raw. See above code edit for reference.

Comment: @steventnorris - If you are using notepad++ to create the files, how are you compiling? Can you post the command that you are using to compile the code?

Comment: The server compiles on the fly thus far using the codebehind and src tags. I could create a config file to compile maybe so i don't have to command line compile everthing every time???

Comment: @steventnorris - Please look at my changed code. It seems to work for me when i changed the namespace from Global to ThisWorks.Fine.

Comment: I'd imagine you're using an IDE like vis studio or something that compiles the .cs into a .dll and places it in the correct folder for you. I do not have this luxury right now, unfortunately. Is there a config file I can create to force the .cs to build to a .dll at the server level, just like the codebehind and src directives do?

Comment: Yes i do have Studio but that should not change the results. BTW, I placed the Tools.cs file inside the App_Code folder. Also, I don't know if it is that you are not allowed to use Studio or not, but there is a free version that you can download.

Comment: It's a corporate wait thing. It's coming to me, but I don't have it yet. And I do not have a App_Code folder accesible to me. The folder I work in reconciles itself to our server, where I'm assuming the web.config and App_Code folder are set up. It may just be something I need to get out system admin to give me some more access too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Tools class is public.

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry, I don't have experience creating applications outside of Visual Studio in this manner. By the way, there are free versions of Visual Studio:  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

Comment: Waiting on a clerance for spending. I'll have vis studio soon hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

C# uses namespaces to separate classes. If you put both classes inside the same namespace, they'll be accessable to each other. Otherwise, use a `using` declaration as in your answer, but specify the *namespace*, not the *filename*.

```
//Tools.cs
namespace MyApp.CoreLogic
{
  class Tools
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then...

```
//Default.cs
namespace MyApp.FrontEnd
{
  using MyApp.CoreLogic

  class Default : Page
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, since you're developing in Notepad++ are you compiling using csc?

The syntax for the compilation should be something like:

```
csc /t:library /out:MyCodeLibrary.dll Tools.cs Default.cs
```

To see the options for csc look at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Note that you can download Visual Studio Express for free and it'll make you much more productive and reduce the confusion in cases such as this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using a shared folder though, so my command line run wouldn't be on the server (not a server admin at the moment). Is there a config file that can be created to tell the server to compile itself?

Comment: I'm not aware of how this can be done remotely.  But the source code shouldn't usually **be** on the server, only the aspx files and the compiled dll - you can create your project locally and then push it to the server to run.  For a web project using Visual Studio you can run a local development web server, which will make you much more productive than developing in Notepad.  Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228041%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for how to develop ASP.NET; it may give you some assistance.